# C# .NET 6 multiple connection via proxy to same port (like 443) connect failed

Tags: c#, networking

When I connect on web via proxy multiple task at the same time, just all tasks timed out.

It's same on TcpClient socks5 proxy. I need help.

This is my testproxy method:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    handler.MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100000;
    handler.Proxy = proxy;
    
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler: handler))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
    
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);

        read = client.GetStringAsync("http://ip-api.com/json").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

This is my testproxy main thread

```
foreach(IWebProxy proxy in proxys) 
{
    new Thread(() => {   
           TestProxy(proxy);
    }).start();
}
```

If proxy count is over 10 - 20, all connect are stopped and timed out.
Any problem with this source code?

**Proxy host / port is same only different Credentials each proxy**

Comment: Documentation says max is 256 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=net-7.0

Comment: `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` don't ever do this. Instead use `await`.

Comment: I don't like telling people do (not) do something without explaining why (they might do something equally bad without even knowing), so just posting a link to explain the previous comment : https://www.nikouusitalo.com/blog/why-is-getawaiter-getresult-bad-in-c/